# convert txt packet data to pcap format to open it by Wireshark

Tags: java, text, converters, pcap

> Hi I am working on application where I have to **read live packets
>   from network** work on it. And display it in sophisticated way.
>
> But **problem is I have packet but it is in text file**, so to open it
>   by Wireshark I have to **convert it in .pcap format**.
>
> So how can I convert packet in text to pcap format.
>
> **My text file format is like this shown below,**

```
Frame:
Frame:          number = 0
Frame:       timestamp = 2014-02-13 09:39:11.288
Frame:     wire length = 174 bytes
Frame: captured length = 174 bytes
Frame:
Eth:  ******* Ethernet - "Ethernet" - offset=0 (0x0) length=14 
Eth: 
Eth:      destination = 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa
Eth:                    .... ..0. .... .... = [0] LG bit
Eth:                    .... ...0 .... .... = [0] IG bit
Eth:           source = ec:9a:74:4d:8e:03
Eth:                    .... ..0. .... .... = [0] LG bit
Eth:                    .... ...0 .... .... = [0] IG bit
Eth:             type = 0x800 (2048) [ip version 4]
Eth: 
Ip:  ******* Ip4 - "ip version 4" - offset=14 (0xE) length=20 protocol suite=NETWORK
Ip: 
Ip:          version = 4
Ip:             hlen = 5 [5 * 4 = 20 bytes, No Ip Options]
Ip:         diffserv = 0x0 (0)
Ip:                    0000 00.. = [0] code point: not set
Ip:                    .... ..0. = [0] ECN bit: not set
Ip:                    .... ...0 = [0] ECE bit: not set
Ip:           length = 160
Ip:               id = 0x4CD1 (19665)
Ip:            flags = 0x0 (0)
Ip:                    0.. = [0] reserved
Ip:                    .0. = [0] DF: do not fragment: not set
Ip:                    ..0 = [0] MF: more fragments: not set
Ip:           offset = 0
Ip:              ttl = 0 [time to live]
Ip:             type = 17 [next: User Datagram]
Ip:         checksum = 0xB0AA (45226) [correct]
Ip:           source = 124.125.80.90
Ip:      destination = 239.255.255.250
Ip: 
Udp:  ******* Udp offset=34 (0x22) length=8 
Udp: 
Udp:           source = 58845
Udp:      destination = 1900
Udp:           length = 140
Udp:         checksum = 0x5154 (20820) [correct]
Udp: 
Data:  ******* Payload offset=42 (0x2A) length=132 
Data: 
002a: 4d 2d 53 45  41 52 43 48  20 2a 20 48  54 54 50 2f    M-SEARCH * HTTP/
003a: 31 2e 31 0d  0a 48 6f 73  74 3a 32 33  39 2e 32 35    1.1..Host:239.25
004a: 35 2e 32 35  35 2e 32 35  30 3a 31 39  30 30 0d 0a    5.255.250:1900..
005a: 53 54 3a 75  72 6e 3a 73  63 68 65 6d  61 73 2d 75    ST:urn:schemas-u
006a: 70 6e 70 2d  6f 72 67 3a  64 65 76 69  63 65 3a 57    pnp-org:device:W
007a: 41 4e 43 6f  6e 6e 65 63  74 69 6f 6e  44 65 76 69    ANConnectionDevi
008a: 63 65 3a 31  0d 0a 4d 61  6e 3a 22 73  73 64 70 3a    ce:1..Man:"ssdp:
009a: 64 69 73 63  6f 76 65 72  22 0d 0a 4d  58 3a 33 0d    discover"..MX:3.
00aa: 0a 0d 0a 00
```

Comment: 1- Is it not feasible from your end to directly read the packets through WireShark ? 
2- How are you getting this text file ?

Comment: Have you tried using a Java pcap library?

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark provides a command line pcap converter for Text Files:

https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html

AutoHotkey solution:

```
; Change appropriate file locations
Run, %A_ProgramFiles%\ethereal\text2pcap.exe c:\test.txt c:\testconv.cap,%A_ProgramFiles%\ethereal
```

If you want to do a fully automated solution you can modify this function which actively watches a directory for file changes/creation.

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/41653-watchdirectory/

Answer (score 0):

If you have raw packets captured you can write them directly to pcap file format (see [man 5 pcap-savefile](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html)) or use hexdump/xxd+text2pcap utility as [ahkcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1914172/ahkcoder) recommends. Text2pcap also supports generation of dummy L2-4 headers (ethernet, ip, tcp/udp/sctp).

If you have only text representation, you can either reconstruct packet from it (so, generate all appropriate headers for each protocol used in your system) or adjust hex dump part offsets (to begin from 0000) and feed it to text2pcap.

Comment: Is there any Java solutions??

Comment: I didn't see any. It's simple and specific problem, so perl/bash/python/ruby can be good languages to solve it.